# Mongoose - Search for text in three fields based on score or weightage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using Mongoose on top of MongoDB. This is how my model looks.

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  viewCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: 'No description'
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  }
    }
});
```

I need to search for some text on over `Name, Description, Body` fields. So far this is what I am doing & its working:

```
Book.find().or([{ 'name': { $regex: term, $options: "$i" }}, { 'description': { $regex: term, $options: "$i" }}, { 'body': { $regex: term, $options: "$i" }}]).exec(
    function (err, topics) {
      if (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
      }
      return res.status(200).json(books);
    });
```

**Problem**: I need to come up with some mechanism where I assign weightage/score to all the fields (`Name,Description,Body`) with `name` having highest weightage, `description` having little less weightage than name and `body` having the least weightage. When the results comes, I want to sort the result by the score/weight.

So far I have looked into this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-score) & [weights](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/), but not sure what is the best way to get the desired result. I **also wants to understand, do I need to create weights every time bebore I search or its a one time activity & how to implemt weights with Mongoose ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ["text index"](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-text/) and [search](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/text/) is indeed likely the best option here as long as you are searching for whole words.

Adding a text index to your schema definition is quite simple:

```
BookSchema.index(
    {
         "name": "text",
         "description": "text",
         "body": "text"
    },
    {
        "weights": {
            "name": 5,
            "description": 2
        }
    }
)
```

This allows you to perform simple searches with "set" weighting to the fields:

```
Book.find({ "$text": { "$search": "Holiday School Year" } })
    .select({ "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } })
    .sort({ "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } })
    .exec(function(err,result) {

    }
);
```

Where each term matched will be considered against the field it was found in which gives the most weight and the number of occurances.

Assigning the weights is attached to the "index", so the definition is done once and cannot be changed. Another limitation is that at "text search" does not look at "partial" words. For example "ci" does not match "City" or "Citizen", and for such a thing you would need a regular expression instead.

If you needed more flexibilty than that or generally must be able to dynamically change the weighting of results then you need something like the aggregation framework or mapReduce.

The aggregation framework however cannot perform a ["logical" match](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/) operation ( it can filter though the `$match` operator, but not a "logical" match ) of a "regular expression" to your terms. You can work with single words and "exact" matches though if this suits.

```
Book.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": {
            "$or": [
                { "name": /Holiday/ },
                { "description": /Holiday/ },
                { "body": /Holiday/ }
            ]
        }},
        { "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "description": 1,
            "body": 1,
            "score": {
                "$add": [
                    { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$name", "Holiday" ] },5,0 ] },
                    { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$description", "Holiday" ] },2,0 ] },
                    { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$body", "Holiday" ] },1,0 ] }
                ]
            }
        }},
        { "$sort": { "score": -1 } }
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
)
```

As an aggregation pipeline uses a data structure to query where you can change the parameters for weight on each exection to whatever you presently need.

MapReduce shares a similar principle, where you can include a calculated "score" in part of the primary key emitted as the leading element. MapReduce naturally sorts all input emitted by this key as an optimization for feeding to a reduce function. However you cannot further sort or "limit" such a result.

Those are generally your options to look at and decide which best suits your case.

Comment: @SharpCoder Every question you are asking is either answered directly in the content of there is a link provided with detais ( as in about "textScore" ). I suggest you read the response again, try things and also read the links.

Comment: You have mentioned `Assigning the weights is attached to the "index", so the definition is done once and cannot be changed`. Does this mens, I need to create index only one??

Comment: @SharpCoder You only ever create an index once, unless you intend to drop the index and redefine it's contents. You really should be reading up on this rather than asking more questions in comments or even posting more questions. There is more than enough example information here to keep you busy for a while.

Comment: i am getting `TypeError: Invalid sort value: {$meta: textScore }` error. I am using mongoDB version 2.6. Any idea where I might go wrong !!

Comment: @SharpCoder You need to "quote" them just as is shown in examples and also in the referenced documentation.

Comment: Apologies for so many comments. The errror message is `TypeError: Invalid sort value: {$meta: textScore }` but the syntax I am using is same as what you have shown. I did looked into documentation and they are also using "quotes"

Comment: @SharpCoder You can hold your aplogies because you have done it many times before. I have made an edit that should be very simple to follow to the letter, I also will note to you, that you have the privileage to "upvote" responses and I have given you several answers which include no such courtesy from yourself. I advice you to be mindful of the "personal time" taken by myself and others reponding to you. And that you "need" go back though those questions and pay a little reward to those who have given you "considerable" help.'

Comment: I will make every effort to accept the answer & upvote the answers that lead me to actual answer !!