# Search functionality for Mongoose collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I've been looking around for a few hours and I can't seem to find anything for this (at least something that isn't outdated).

So I have a search box in my view and I am listing out all users in a table and I want to be able to search the list of users by a few fields like `name`, `email`, `city` etc.

Here is the route for listing all users

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.render('dashboard/index.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
      users: users
    });
  });
});
```

How would I go about implementing search? Can I do this using mongoose directly, or do I have to use a package.

I'm all ears on suggestions.

Comment: Possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063998/

Comment: By duplicate you mean one way of doing search functionality, right? @chridam

Comment: The referenced post has got an answer which addresses your question above if I understood correctly, hence why I believe it's a duplicate post.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use `mongoose` for it. You already doing some search by issuing `{}`. Just add whatever you want to your search object:

```
User.find({name: "foo", city: "bar"}, ...);
```

Will search for Users matching "foo" and "bar" in their appropriate fields.

Comment: How would I search using a search bar in the view? How would I go about connecting it so users can actually be searched?

Comment: So for example if someone searched for "Joe" in the search bar, it would return all users named Joe etc.